# How to change font color in .net 4 Chart

Tags: c#, .net, mschart

I want to change font of labels for this chart:

[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4563/chartjk.png](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4563/chartjk.png)

How to do it in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already found how to do it:

```
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#517985");
```